# MongoDB / GridFS + Tomcat troubles

Tags: mongodb, tomcat, gridfs

I'm running an application on Tomcat 7, running on a virtual machine, meant for one purpose : distributing photos.

When initializing the application, it connects with MongoDB like :

```
//Create mongo reference
Mongo mongo = new Mongo(new MongoURI(url));
```

Then I keep the reference in memory and go to search the photo like this :

```
//Update R/W Strategy
dbManager.setMongoReadWritePreferences(mongo, app);

//Use database dbname
DB db = mongo.getDB(dbname);

try {           
    db.requestStart();
    db.requestEnsureConnection();

    //Open gridFS connection
    GridFS fs = new GridFS(db, GlobalConfig.GRIDFS_COLLECTION_BUCKET_BLOBS);

    GridFSDBFile photos = fs.findOne(filename);
    log.debug("[+]"+photos);

    if (photos == null){
        throw new Exception("[PHOTO_NOT_FOUND]");
    } else {
        return photos.getInputStream();
    }

} finally {
    //Request is finished
    db.requestDone();
}
```

It's working quite well. (*~35ms for any photo, on a 70GB set of photos*)

I recently started to have troubles with photos not returned, and strange peaks on my monitoring graphs :

[image: Thread count]
[image: Requests per mins]
[image: Mean time]
[image: Bytes per mins]

The traffic is not really high, but it keeps doing the weird things, sending null photos randomly.

Anyone has a clue of what could it be ?

Comment: Isn't really enough information to go by .. you do have a sudden increase in the number of threads and activity from 21:00, but does this line up with your normal site usage patterns ?  Are these servers in MMS?

Comment: Hi Stennie, thanks for your reply. The server is self-hosted on a virtual machine. It looks like my problem has been solved by restarting the physical machine .. but i still don't know what was giving this. I'll delete this post.